# CakePHP Auth accepting any username/password

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I've been working with Auth for a couple days now and I thought that it was working properly but it seems to be allowing any username or password. I am using a custom model (Employee) with a custom field (username => employee_id).

**The page always returns "good!"**

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'flashElement' => 'login_error',
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'Employees',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'all' => array('userModel' => 'Employee'),
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Employee',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'employee_id',
                        'password' => 'password',
                    )
                )
            )   
        ),
    );

    public $uses = array(
        'ProgramApplication',
        'Employee'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->fields = array(
            'username' => 'employee_id',
            'password' => 'password'
        );
```

**EmployeesController**

```
public function index() {
        //Set layout to login
        $this->layout = 'login';

        $this->request->data['Employee']['password'] = md5($this->request->data['Employee']['password'].$salt);

         //if already logged-in, redirect
        if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
            return $this->redirect(
            array('controller' => 'Search', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
        print_r($this->request->data);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {
                echo "good!";
                //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                echo "no good";
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
```

**Index.ctp**

```
<form id='Employee' role="form" action='' method="post">
  <div id='username' class="form-group">

    <input type="username" name='data[Employee][username]' id='EmployeeUsername' onblur="checkUsername()" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="password" name='data[Employee][password]' class="form-control" id="EmployeePassword" placeholder="Password">
    <a href=""<?php echo EWConfig::$URL?>/ExpressWay/Employees/passwordReset"">Forgot password?</a>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: "$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)" => The next one who didnt read the docs. Please see the 100 other question which have the same error. The docs clearly state that you should not pass anything in login() or your login is pointless.

Comment: Just noticed that. Although my problem now is its not accepting anything. Do my inputs look correct in the index.ctp?

Comment: Why are you not using the Form helper? You should do that. Why are you manually hashing? The Auth component takes care of that. Follow the conventions and it will all work out of the box.

Comment: I find it difficult to incorporate bootstrap and a custom auth model with the Form helper but it seems like the only option I have.

Comment: See http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/ - Also https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/Authenticate of ideas how to properly design Auth adapters. Embrace the framework - dont fight it.

Comment: Thanks for that! I believe the problem is with the manual hashing. Using $this->Auth->login() results in no username/password getting passed which is most likely from Cake rehashing the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

Also see the red warning box at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in